# Disable vertical scroll in UIScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

(Don't mark this question as duplicated. I read a lot of questions but I don't find the answer to my issue.)

My issue is the following: I have a `UIScrollView` which is supposed to only scroll horizontally. Here it scrolls vertically for 20px (strange fact: it appears to be the same height of the status bar).

I tried to print the content size, the y offset and the height of the `UIScrollView` like this:

```
print(horizontalScrollView.contentSize)
print(horizontalScrollView.bounds.size.height)
print(horizontalScrollView.contentOffset.y)
```

I get this:

```
(1125.0, 667.0). // scrollview content size
667.0.           // scrollview height
-20.0            // content offset (y)
```

I know that the `scrollView` content size height must be <= `scrollView` height. And as you can see this is the case.

I use constraints to put 3 `UIViewController` stacked horizontally. And it works well except of this issue.

Another fact: It worked before Swift 4 and Xcode 9... I don't know if this could be the cause or not.

Do you have some ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since iOS 11 content insets can get adjusted automatically. Try setting your scrollview's behaviour to not adjust it.

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    scrollview.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You can simply do this. **Swift 4**

```
self.scrollView.contentSize.height = 1.0 // disable vertical scroll
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for attempting to answer the question, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: If you want to disable Scrolling but keep the actual content offset : scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false . Set it to TRUE to enable scrolling again.

Comment: @Fox5150 yes but that also disables horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 17):

very charm solution is:

```
     // also don't forget
     // YourViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.scrollView.delegate = self
  }

  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 || scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

****Swift 5****

```
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Comment: won't this disable both vertical and horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 1):

just set the contentOffset in scrollViewDidScroll

```
if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0)
}
```

Comment: I know this method but it's not clean. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use next class, setting `canScroll` as needed:

```
class BlockScrollView: UIScrollView {
    var canScroll = true

    override func setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool) {
        if canScroll {
            super.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add single Line

```
yourScrollView.bounces = false
```

and make Sure your scroll view subview(Content) height is equal to you scrollview height
And you're Done

Answer (score 0):

In swift

> self.scrollView.contentSize.width = 1.0 // disable vertical scroll