# Why UICollectionViewController makes initial vertical offset of it's view property of 64 point?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

UICollectionViewController is the root view controller of UINavigationViewController. This offset is not offset for navigbar + status bar, this offset starting right below navig bar 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz964D-WrU9Kd2h6SkZjZFFXeDg this picture for detailing. thanks for everyone in advance

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your collection view has an Y offset which you don't want? Probably your view controller's `edgesForExtendedLayout` is set to `.all` or `.top` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true`

Comment: no automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets sets to false

Comment: Check my answer here, could be this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46564109/1433612 I am slightly guessing here, because I do not quite understand if your problem is the content offset or the frame of your collection view.